What is the difference between using TypeScript generics and type assertions with document.querySelector
I’m trying to understand the difference, if any, between these two ways of calling a generic method in TypeScript:
const input1 = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(".myClass");

const input2 = document.querySelector(".myClass") as HTMLInputElement;

The obvious distinction is that input1 could be HTMLInputElement or null, while input2 explicitly casts the result as an HTMLInputElement, potentially ignoring the null case.
However, if I change the second example to account for null, like this:
const input2 = document.querySelector(".myClass") as HTMLInputElement | null;

then both seem equivalent. Is there any practical or subtle difference between using generics and type assertions in this context, or are these two approaches effectively the same when null is considered?
Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

This depends greatly on the generic function in question. In the specific case that you mention, there isn't any difference.
Frankly I consider the generic type parameter here to be a bad API choice. The whole reason JSON.parse is not generic is to avoid this exact problem where you cosplay at type safety by passing a generic where the value is completely unknowable until runtime (unless you're selecting by tag name, but your example uses a CSS class).
Not all generics are this way however:
const stuff: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
const foo: string = stuff.pop();           // compile error!
const bar: string = stuff.pop() as string; // compiler silent, fails at runtime!!!

Here the generic is actually enforced, for any value that has a type which isn't number. So in your case the generic is a lie and it makes no difference, but that's the result of an unfortunate API choice, usually the generic is enforced by the compiler but the cast with as crucially is not!

"cosplay at type safety" <--
